# How to use a dictionary of arrays to loop through worksheets

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to make something that

1. loops through a range (header range) of values and collects them into an array or whatever
2. make a dictionary of arrays with keys that are the values in the range
3. loop through worksheets looking for those keys
4. for each key it finds,

   a. make an array of the values below

   b. pad all the arrays so their the same length

   c. concatenate it to the array stored in the dictionary with the same key
5. copy the concatenated values back to the cells below the header range

I did 1,2,4 and 5. I skipped 3, because that's easy and I'll do it later.  But 4 is tricky because I can't get a handle on how the dictionary and arrays work. I tried to make a dictionary of arrays, but they're making copies instead of references and sometimes the copies are empty. I don't know.

In javascript, it would just be:

- make a `dict = {}`
- loop through the values and do `dict[value] = []`
- then `dict[value].concatenate(newestarray)`
- Then flip the dict back in to an array with a `for(var k in dict){}` which in google sheets you would have to transpose. Annoying, but not terrible.
- Then in the end, some function to put it back into the worksheet, which in google sheets would be trivial.

Here's my code for the 4 part:

```
With rws
    For Each Key In headerdict 'loop through the keys in the dict
        Set rrng = .Cells.Find(key, , _ 'find the key in the sheet
            Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, _
            Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, False)

        If rrng Is Not Empty Then
            'find last cell in column of data
            Set rdrng = .Cells(rws.Rows.Count, rrng.Column).End(xlUp)
            'get range for column of data
            Set rrng = .Range(.Cells(rrng.Row + 1, rrng.Column), _
                .Cells(rdrng.Row, rdrng.Column))
            rArray = rrng.Value 'make an array
            zMax = Max(UBound(rArray, 2), zMax) 'set max list length
            fakedict(Key) = rArray 'place array in fake dict for later smoothing

        End If
    Next
End With

For Each Key In fakedict 'now smooth the array
    If fakedict(Key) Is Not Nothing Then
        nArray = fakedict(Key)
        ReDim Preserve nArray(1 To zMax, 1 To 1) 'resize the array

    Else
        ReDim nArray(1 To zMax, 1 To 1) 'or make one from nothing
    End If
    fakedict(Key) = nArray 'add to fake dict
Next
```

Then later I can combine into the real dict. So my question is how do I resize the array? I don't think redim preserve is the best way. Others have mangled with collections, but I have too much pandas and python thinking.  I'm used to deal with vectors, not munge elements. Any ideas?

Comment: `ReDim Preserve` is the way I think although for `2D` arrays, you can only resize the last dimension (like you'll have fixed number of fields, you can only add/resize records). So this line `ReDim Preserve nArray(1 To zMax, 1 To 1)` will probably fail since you re-dimension the 1st dimension. Now, maybe you can transfer this array first to another *fake* array and then re-create another *notsofake* array to consolidate values and then re-assign in the corresponding key of the *fakedict*.

Comment: Worth noting that if you have an array stored as a dictionary value, you first need to copy it out into a temp variable before you can do anything with it (like adding items).  When you're done modifying the array, copy it back into the dictionary.

Comment: Depending on the size of the array you can always transpose the array, redim the new 2nd dimension (i.e. the swopped first) and then re-transpose.

Comment: You can also oversize the array first, employ a counter of some sort to get the final size and then do one redim at the end (using the counter variable to determine max size). Less redims = less copies = more efficient, I believe.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yeah Tim good point and I think that's what OP did, see the `For Loop` part.

Comment: To L42.  How did you edit it so nice?  It took me 20 minutes just to get it in its original state.  I had to trick the editor by making some of my paragraphs into code.

Comment: @HenriettaMartingale Are the values that should be "harvested" some specific kind? Maybe you could workaround arrays by storing joined values in your dictionary? Also, why do you actually want to resize all the arrays stored in the dictionary?

Comment: I have six or seven workbooks and unknown worksheets in them where I have to pull the data if its true.  I can either copy and paste the data back and forth between the worksheets, or I just store it all in an array and write the array back into the one big worksheet in the end with range.values = array

Comment: Quick question - where you've got a comment "find last cell in column of data," the code says `Set rdrng = ... .End(xlUp)` Is xlUp correct here?

Comment: @PeterHull Note that the row value in `.Cells()` -- i.e. `rws.Rows.count` -- is the total number of rows. That places the `.Cells()` as the last row in the specific column. The `End(xlUp)` is then used to find the first cell above which is not blank. This "backwards" method is often used when the cells with data are not continuous throughout the entire used section of a column..

Comment: @Mistella neat trick, I hadn't thought of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not sure if you *needed* to use a dictionary of arrays to achieve this; if I was doing it I would just copy blocks of cells between sheets directly.
First bit - identify where the headers are:

```
Option Explicit
' Get the range that includes the headers
' Assume the headers are in sheet "DB" in row 1
Private Function GetHeaders() As Range
Dim r As Range
Set r = [DB!A1]
Set GetHeaders = Range(r, r.End(xlToRight))
End Function
```

Second, identify the sheets to scan (I assumed they're in the same workbook)

```
' Get all sheets in this workbook that aren't the target DB sheet
Private Function GetSheets() As Collection
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim col As New Collection
For Each sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  If sheet.Name <> "DB" Then col.Add sheet
Next sheet
Set GetSheets = col
End Function
```

Now, scan through and copy cells

```
' Main function, loop through all headers in all sheets
' and copy data
Sub CollectData()
Dim sheets As Collection, sheet As Worksheet
Dim hdrs As Range, hdr As Range
Dim found As Range
' This is the row we are writing into on DB
Dim currentrow As Integer
' This is the maximum number of entries under a header on this sheet, used for padding
Dim maxcount As Integer
Set sheets = GetSheets
Set hdrs = GetHeaders
currentrow = 1
For Each sheet In sheets
    maxcount = 0
    For Each hdr In hdrs.Cells
    ' Assume each header appears only once in each sheet
        Set found = sheet.Cells.Find(hdr.Value)
        If Not found Is Nothing Then
            ' Check if there is anything underneath
            If Not IsEmpty(found.Offset(1).Value) Then
                Set found = Range(found.Offset(1), found.End(xlDown))
                ' Note the number of items if it's more that has been  found so far
                If maxcount < found.Count Then maxcount = found.Count
                ' Copy cells
                Range(hdr.Offset(currentrow), hdr.Offset(currentrow + found.Count - 1)) = found.Cells.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next hdr
    ' Move down ready for the next sheet
    currentrow = currentrow + maxcount
Next sheet
End Sub
```

I wrote this in Excel 2016 and tested that it worked based on my assumption of how your data is laid out.